# I want to print triangle in stars pattern in PHP can anyone help, Just using two for loops only to solve it?

Tags: php, web

Please give me the solution for to print a triangle in stars pattern using php language. I used only 2 for loops to finish this.

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
for($a=1;$a<=7;$a++)
{
    for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
    {
        echo " *";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
echo " ";
?>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Plagiarism on Assignment Number #1?

Comment: yes exactly assignment number #1 ^_^

Comment: @chris85 , Hello sir I am new in coding so i am not creating any problems for you to understand my wrong questions. That's why I am not provide you the code.

Comment: Now I have written my code please help.

Comment: Okay, with code this is a better question. In the future please include the code with your question. This is in a browser or where? You need to add spaces/padding around the `*` so the triangle forms.

Comment: Thanks sir, will you help me for this question and give me the solution of code with only 2 for loops to done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, still uses two for loops:

```
echo "<pre>";
$stars = "*";
for($a=1; $a<=4; $a++)
{
    $spaces = "";
    for($b = (5 - $a); $b>1; $b--)
    {
        $spaces .= " ";
    }
    echo $spaces . $stars . $spaces;
    $stars .= "**";
    echo "<br/>";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

I've used an accumulator for $stars, it starts from one star, an adds two stars at each iteration, and one accumulator for $spaces, that gets reset at each main for iteration. 
The triangle is build top to bottom using one layer at a time. 
One layer is made of spaces, stars and spaces again

Comment: Did you check output in the questions description.

Comment: It is prints stars in the same pattern as like what my code does @Dan Ionescu

Comment: Yes it prints the stars like the pattern you provided

Comment: But sir i need triangle shape for the stars

Comment: If you output that in a browser put: echo "<pre>"; before and echo "</pre>"; after the script; or replace $spaces .= " "; with $spaces .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;";

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
for($i=0; $i < 5 ; $i++)
{

echo"<br>";
for($j=0; $j <=$i ; $j++){
echo "*" ;
}

} 
?>
```

[For more php Star patterns](https://www.deshgyanupdates.com/star-pattern-using-php/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++) {
        for($y = 0; $y < $n - $x; $y++) {
            echo ' ';
        }
        for($z = 0; $z < $x * 2 +1; $z++) {
            echo 'x';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
```